# Xcode - symbol not found importing big bsd project

Tags: xcode, macos

#### Context:

OSX yosemite 10.10.3
Xcode 6.3.1

Importing freebsd tree in xcode.
Works beautifully in eclipse.
Sucks in xcode.

Xcode takes it very fine if I create a new project with a few files.

I am new to xcode though.

#### Problem:

When I command click on most (~95%) variables / functions xcode tells me `symbol not found`. Works perfectly in eclipse.

After importing and recreating the index (deleting the DerivedData) the problem is still there.

#### Question:

Do I miss something ? Not so many options in xcode as it seems.
Is xcode only for apple'ish code ?
Is freebsd code too large to be handled correctly?

Comment: Why do you use eclipse ? Coding in native or what ?

Comment: The goal is to load the C code in a qemu then. I come from the linux world you know but willing to embrace fully osx.

Comment: How did it work in eclipse?  Are you sure it didn't just read the Makefiles or something?  If so, there is nothing like that for Xcode.

Comment: No, it is a builtin feature, the index. Xcode has it too and it works but on a small scale project. I need to take care of hundreds and hundreds of files

Comment: Sounds like you need to use eclipse then.

Comment: Ah ok.. shame.. xcode seemed very fine to use

Comment: It is. It knocks eclipse into a cocked hat, however this use-case is very rare I would imagine.

Comment: I am sure about that..